# CSP DLLs still needed to be signed?

Tags: code-signing, mscapi

I'm developing a custom CSP and I want to use it from Adobe Reader but it is not very clear to me if it still needs to be signed because [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/ro-ro/windows-hardware/drivers/install/authenticode-signing-of-csps) there is a note:

> "Starting with Windows 8, it is no longer a requirement that CSPs must
> be signed."

So, it mustn't be signed, am I right?

I'm asking this because from a custom test program (a c++ console) the CSP works fine but when I want to use it with sigtool.exe or Adobe Reader, my CSP DLL is not called.

Comment: It doesn't say that it should not be signed. It says that it does not need to be. You can still sign it if other tools need it to be signed.

Comment: @schroeder i think that you are right. I will try with a self signed code signing certificate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSP mustn't need to be signed. The problem was at the dependencies.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).